# Looking for Gitlab feature as Circle CI context

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In Circle CI, `context` can allow me to set different values for same variables.

For example, I set two environments, such as `dev` and `prod`, in each of them, I set several variables

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Since my environments are in different aws accounts, I can provide the different values to them.

Second, I can set permission that developers can only access `dev` context, support team can only access `prod` context.

But I don't get the same feature in Gitlab CI.

In one of their document, it mentions `Group`, but after I check, it doesn't work as expect at all.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/migration/circleci.html#contexts-and-variables

> Contexts and variables
> CircleCI provides [Contexts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/) to securely pass environment variables across project pipelines. In GitLab, a [Group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html) can be created to assemble related projects together. At the group level, [CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-group) can be stored outside the individual projects, and securely passed into pipelines across multiple projects.

Are there any way I can do that in Gitlab CI?

Sample usage of context in Circli CI for your reference

```
version: 2.1

workflows:
  staging-workflow:
    jobs:
      - staging-build:
          context:
            - staging

  prod-workflow:
    jobs:
      - prod-build:
          context:
            - prod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this problem fixed with [Gitlab CI enviroments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/)

1. set environments **Staging** and **Produciton**
   when it asks for url, ignore the issue, put any url you like, I just put http://example.com .

still not sure the proper url I need put in.

2. update your variables in cicd, default is to all, change it to staging or Production.

Setting -> CICD -> Variables -> Expand

[image]

in the screenshot, I set variable **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** two times, but assigned to different environments.

(Notes: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` doesn't need be masked, but `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` should be)

3. update your pipeline to use the enviroment.

the gitlab ci environment document above confuse me again. **you don't have to provide the url**, just add the environment name is enough.

```
staging_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "staging deployment"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve something similar by utilising gitlabs schedules.

Simply create two schedules that contain the variables you want to pass.

Update your ci script to reference these variables.

Then each schedule can be owned by the respective parties.

You can also limit variables by group, based on which environment. So if you have a dev env - variables can be limited for that and the same for a prod env. Hope this helps.

Comment: Schedule? there is nothing to do with Schedule (cron).

Comment: No. I’m suggesting using the schedules within gitlab as a way to manage the different groups of variables. You can also set schedules to be deactivated and then they become a manually activated way to execute a particular job with its own defined variables.

Comment: but it can't set in normal pipeline process, right? and have to stick on particular branches.

Comment: for the group in gitlab ci, I have the feeling that the function mentioned in gitlab document is not available for free users. So I can't see the setting when I try to set variables in group

Comment: confirmed, if the group is created by me, I can see `setting` in my group. But with the company group, I have no permission to see `setting` and `CI/CD`

Comment: found another feature in Gitlab, called environment but not sure how to set the External URL. I will update in my original question